# How do I make my Volley response into a variable, so I can pass the value on to another activity using intents?

Tags: android, variables, android-volley

I'm trying to assign my Volley response to a variable, so I can pass the value on to another activity using intents.

I'm wondering why my `theMatchingContacts` string is showing `null` in logcat. I'm seeing `the matching contacts are null`

I have `theMatchingContacts` declared at the top of my activity:

```
public class VerifyUserPhoneNumber extends AppCompatActivity  {

String theMatchingContacts;
```

If the user is registered for the app, which is the case, then in `onCreate` :

```
else {

         getPhoneContacts();

        // then start the next activity
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(VerifyUserPhoneNumber.this, PopulistoListView.class);
        //we need phoneNoofUser so we can get user_id and corresponding
        //reviews in the next activity
        myIntent.putExtra("keyName", phoneNoofUser);
        myIntent.putExtra("JsonArrayMatchingContacts", theMatchingContacts);
        System.out.println("phonenoofuser" + phoneNoofUser);
        System.out.println("the matching contacts are " + theMatchingContacts);

        VerifyUserPhoneNumber.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

I'm seeing `phoneNoofUser` alright, that works. But for `theMatchingContacts` it prints `null`. And the function `getPhoneContacts()` which happens before the `Intents` part calls the volley code below, so `getMatchingContacts` should be initialized, right?

My volley code, further down, is:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, CHECKPHONENUMBER_URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println(response);

                theMatchingContacts = response.toString();

                System.out.println(theMatchingContacts );

                   etc...etc...
```

The `response` prints correctly. So does `theMatchingContacts` , in the Volley part of the code. I can't put the Intents code into the Volley call as my activity needs to do other things before calling `startActivity`

Comment: if you want to do any main thread related work then try using `runOnUiThread() ` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute code that starts new Activity in `OnResponse` callback method of Volley Request, because, as Bob says, Volley Request is asynchronous and you want go to next Activity when this request has finished.

Answer (score 1):

Volley executes the request asynchronously in a background thread. So the order of execution in the main thread will be like this:

1. `getPhoneContacts();` is called
2. Volley starts the network request in a worker thread
3. The next `Activity` `PopulistoListView` is started with null value for `theMatchingContacts`
4. Volley request gets finished and sets the value for `theMatchingContacts` in the `onResponse`.

So by the time you are starting the `PopulistoListView` `Activity`, the value of `theMatchingContacts` is still `null`, because the Volley request hasn't been completed yet.